# XMLHttpRequest only check server is connect or not, It is not check the URL

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, xmlhttprequest

```
function check()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{
            // code for IE6, IE5
            var request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        dname="http://www.w3schools.com/js/default/gfdghkjfdh.html";
        request.open("HEAD", dname,true);
        request.send();
        if(request.status !== 404){ 
            window.location.href=dname;
        }
        else{
            window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
        }
    }
```

The above code only check whether the server is connected or not, It doesn't check the URL's last part "gfdghkjfdh.html" is available or not.

There is any way to check the the URL "http://www.w3schools.com/js/default/gfdghkjfdh.html"
Correctly using javascript or any clientside technology.
Plz anybody help me

Answer (score 0):

> The above code only check whether the server is connected or not, It doesn't check the URL's last part "gfdghkjfdh.html" is available or not.

No, it doesn't. XHR makes an HTTP request to the third party server, doesn't get a CORS header giving it permission to expose the information it got from that server to JavaScript running on someone else's page, then doesn't expose the status to the script.

> There is any way to check the the URL `"http://www.w3schools.com/js/default/gfdghkjfdh.html"` Correctly using javascript or any clientside technology.

JavaScript? No.

Other client side technology? Maybe.

A signed Java applet might be able to (if the user is running on a platform that supports Java (so not mobile), and has Java installed, and accepts the security alerts, and allows Java in the browser in the first place (which isn't a great idea given the number of recent security problems it has had)).

An ActiveX control might be able to (if the user is running a sufficiently old version of Internet Explorer on Windows, and accepts the security alerts).

Flash … probably couldn't. I think it requires a crossdomain.xml file to give it permission.

So, other client side technology? Maybe, but not in any practical way.

You could make an XMLHttpRequest to your own server, then have your own server try to contact the third-party server. This would increase the load on your own server and sometimes to connectivity between your server and the third-party server will be different to that between it and the client.

Comment: Nice answer Quentin. Removing mine :)

Comment: Thanks you for the answer.if using HTML5 web socket there is any way tosolve the above problem